# Hadoop Disaster Recovery

Tags: hadoop, recovery

Anyone could help me to know about Hadoop Disaster Recovery ?

should i replicate data from cluster to another cluster as backup use distcp?
Or i can use copyToLocal to copy my data to my localmachine ?

Anyone idea about it ?

Answer (score 3):

DRP plan goes beyond just the technology and the requirements can greatly affect the solution.

for instance if you can't afford to lose any data you'd want an active/active setup and send data to two hadoop clusters simultaneously. on the other side of the spectrum hadoop's replication (default is 3 copies but you can change that) and rack awareness can give you a copy on a secondary rack. In between you can use things like distcp that you mention to copy data from cluster to cluster.

Additionally you might want to follow [project falcon](http://hortonworks.com/blog/project-falcon-tackling-hadoop-data-lifecycle-management-via-community-driven-open-source/) which is a new initiative for hadoop data life-cycle management